Doubling the numbers within an image matrix
I have an image Matrix tag that looks like this
<matrix type="MATRIX" nScaleBits="18" nTranslateBits="14" scaleX="66428" scaleY="66427" translateX="-40" translateY="6054"/>
I guess it looks like this in its real form:
\begin{bmatrix}66428&0&-40\\0&66427&6054\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
There's some software I'm using which automatically doubles the image size, and returns this matrix which is somehow correct:
<matrix type="MATRIX" nScaleBits="0" nTranslateBits="0" scaleX="132856" scaleY="132854" translateX="-3020" translateY="8538"/>
\begin{bmatrix}132856&0&-3020\\0&132854&8538\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
So I understand the ScaleX and ScaleY attributes are simply getting multiplied by 2, but I'm so confused on how -40 becomes -3020 and 6054 becomes 8538.
So to clarify, what equations might I have to do for 6054 to become 8538, using only the given numbers and maybe some of the more basic ones (1,2,5,10,20)
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm terrible at math

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
